# Unable To Load Moved Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

I am in a real bind here. A programmer long before me made several applications in VS2010. We needed to move all these old applications to a file server so they can be backed up etc while awaiting updates. I am attempting to open this solution "Intranet". However, when I attempt this I receive the following error message: 
***\fs01\it$\Application-Source-Code\Projects-Important\Projects-Important\FFL Programs\Intranet\ : 
error  : Error opening web \fs01\it$\Application-Source-Code\Projects-Important\Projects-Important\FFL Programs\Intranet.
Unable to open the Web site '\fs01\it$\Application-Source-Code\Projects-Important\Projects-Important\FFL Programs\Intranet'.
The Web site '\fs01\it$\Application-Source-Code\Projects-Important\Projects-Important\FFL Programs\Intranet' does not exist.***

We have a big customer coming in tomorrow morning and I need to take a look at the code to fix an error "a master page error". However, I cannot open this using VS2017 Version Selector. I have attached a screen shot of the sln file into to help assist with a resolution.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

- Copy your code from your file server (VS2010) see if it is opening/working on your local dev machine (in VS2010 orvs2017)

IF NOT
Option 2:

- Still you'll need the above project files, now...
- Create a blank solution in VS 2017 (relative to your programming language i.e. C# or Vb.Net etc) - also look for target framework
- Locate the project file(s) (for e.g. ".csproj" files for c# projects) one by one manually.
- Try to build the individual project( should there be any missing assembly references) and followed by complete solution build.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, this is a VB.NET website vs project. Sorry that I referenced incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

@NBaua, My brain has been overwhelmed lately. I was attempting to open a project when I needed to open a website. I just went to File --> Open --> Website and all works. Thanks again.